# Lua add a instance field to userdata with C++

Tags: c++, lua

I want to add some static fields to my Lua userdata objects coming from C++. The objects in question are vectors, they're created in C++ land and they work as they are but I've tried `lua_setfield` on my userdata but I get a `attempt to index a Vector value` error and I don't really want to have to use `.x(), .y(), .z()` due to the cost of having to call a function, push to stack and then read on the Lua side.

Is there any way to register fields on userdata for Lua access?

Answer (score -1):

Userdata doesn't have "fields". What it *can* have is a metatable, for which you can define the `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods. Given such a metatable, the former function is called when reading the value of a field of the userdata, while the latter is called when assigning a value to a field from the outside (`ud.some_field = 4` or an equivalent). If you want fields to be read only (to some degree), you can just implement `__index`, and attempts by the user to use `__newindex` will fail.

So in your C++ code, after creating the userdata, you can use `lua_setmetatable` to assign it a table that has these methods defined within it. Of course, these functions will need to access the actual C++ object from the userdata and fetch the specific values you're interested in.

Comment: Thats a shame, that's just as expensive as defining a meta method for the components, except a whole lot less clear in the source. Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to do the reverse? If I push a table to the stack with the values can I assign userdata as the metastable for the methods it has such as length and dot?

Comment: @DaveMackintosh: "*that's just as expensive as defining a meta method for the components*" It's not expensive at all. It's how most Lua interfaces work. "*push a table to the stack with the values*" A table with what values? And why would a table need metamethods?

Comment: I mean to hold the components of the vector, so a table with `.x, .y, .z, .w` and the metamethods of the `Vector` user data so I can call `myVector:Length()` and `myVector * myOtherVector` etc.

Comment: @DaveMackintosh: I don't see why you would need a metatable to make `myVector:Length()` work. If `myVector` is a Lua table, then it can have a key "Length" which has a function to compute the length, just like you would do in Lua. The only reason for a metatable would be to allow for vector math. But at this point, your code lives *entirely* in Lua, so you would no longer be dealing with objects "coming from C++", "created in C++ land".